# Internal Server Error ;( Setting up server of Amazon EC2 with Python Flask )

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask

I am trying to make my server run with EC2, when visited it gives:

Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Code can be found at : https://github.com/amrfarid140/CatalogEC2

for apache error.log:

```
[Sat Mar 05 14:39:51.558283 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2651:tid 140164302710656] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-10-20-18-130
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Mar 05 14:39:51.564079 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2651:tid 140164302710656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 05 14:39:51.564095 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2651:tid 140164302710656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Mar 05 14:42:49.305564 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2651:tid 140164302710656] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-10-20-18-130
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Mar 05 14:42:49.310625 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2651:tid 140164302710656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 05 14:42:49.310640 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2651:tid 140164302710656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Mar 05 15:09:30.180818 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2651:tid 140164302710656] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 05 15:09:31.172919 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3685:tid 139877376771968] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 05 15:09:31.172989 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3685:tid 139877376771968] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Mar 05 16:32:21.194956 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3685:tid 139877376771968] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 05 16:32:22.184800 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4556:tid 139681590728576] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 05 16:32:22.184871 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4556:tid 139681590728576] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Mar 05 16:33:57.787514 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4556:tid 139681590728576] AH00045: child process 4560 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sat Mar 05 16:33:59.792648 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4556:tid 139681590728576] AH00045: child process 4560 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sat Mar 05 16:34:01.794970 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4556:tid 139681590728576] AH00045: child process 4560 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sat Mar 05 16:34:03.797396 2016] [core:error] [pid 4556:tid 139681590728576] AH00046: child process 4560 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Sat Mar 05 16:34:04.798716 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4556:tid 139681590728576] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 05 16:34:05.523737 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4749:tid 139813688158080] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 05 16:34:05.523811 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4749:tid 139813688158080] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Mar 05 16:37:51.054771 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4749:tid 139813688158080] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-10-20-18-130
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Mar 05 16:37:51.060082 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4749:tid 139813688158080] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 05 16:37:51.060099 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4749:tid 139813688158080] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

catalog.wgsi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/catalog')

from application import app as application
```

Application.py:

```
# setup flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify, flash, g, session
from flask.ext.seasurf import SeaSurf
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = SeaSurf(app)
# setup ssl if needed
"""import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.load_cert_chain('/etc/ssl/private/server.pem')"""

# setup client id and secret of github application for oauth
from flask.ext.github import GitHub

# config application
app.config['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'] = 'XXX'
app.config['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'YYY'
app_secret = 'ZZZ'
github_callback_url = "https://dev.anryousef.de/github-callback"
github = GitHub(app)

# setup sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, desc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from database_setup import Base, Category, Item, User

engine = create_engine("postgresql://catalog:qazzaq@localhost/catalog")

Base.metadata.bind = engine

# http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

Base.query = db_session.query_property()

# flask functions
##################


@app.route('/')


@app.route('/catalog/')
def showCatalog():
    categories = Category.query.all()
    items = Item.query.order_by(Item.created.desc()).all()
    return render_template('catalog.html', categories=categories, items=items, user=g.user)


@app.route('/catalog/<string:category_name>/')


def showCategory(category_name):

    categories = Category.query.all()
    category = Category.query.filter_by(name=category_name).one()
    items = Item.query.filter_by(category=category).all()
    return render_template('catalog.html', categories=categories, items=items, category=category, user=g.user)


@app.route('/item/<int:item_id>/')


def showItem(item_id):

    item = Item.query.filter_by(id=item_id).one()
    return render_template('item.html', item=item, user=g.user)


@app.route('/catalog/<string:category_name>/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])



def addItem(category_name):

    categories = Category.query.all()
    category = Category.query.filter_by(name=category_name).one()
    user = g.user
    # check if user is authenticated
    if user is not None:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # check if an item name was entered
            if request.form['name'] != "":
                mycategory = Category.query.filter_by(
                    name=request.form['category']).one()
                item = Item(name=request.form['name'],
                            image=request.form['image'],
                            description=request.form['description'],
                            category=mycategory,
                            owner=user)
                db_session.add(item)
                db_session.commit()
                flash("Item " + item.name + " added to " + item.category.name)
                return redirect(url_for('showCategory', category_name=mycategory.name))
            else:
                flash("Item name must not be empty")
                return redirect(url_for('addItem', category_name=category_name))
        else:
            return render_template('additem.html', category=category, categories=categories, user=user)
    else:
        flash("Unauthorized user")
        return redirect(url_for('showCatalog'))


@app.route('/item/<int:item_id>/edit/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])



def editItem(item_id):

    item = Item.query.filter_by(id=item_id).one()
    user = g.user
    # check if user is owner
    if user == item.owner:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # check if an item name was entered
            if request.form['name'] != "":
                item.name = request.form['name']
                item.image = request.form['image']
                item.description = request.form['description']
                if request.form['category']:
                    category = Category.query.filter_by(
                        name=request.form['category']).one()
                    item.category = category
                db_session.add(item)
                db_session.commit()
                flash("Item " + item.name + " saved")
                return redirect(url_for('showItem', item_id=item.id))
            else:
                flash("Item name must not be empty")
                return redirect(url_for('editItem', item_id=item.id))
        else:
            categories = Category.query.all()
            return render_template('edititem.html', item=item, categories=categories, user=user)
    else:
        flash("Unauthorized user")
        return redirect(url_for('showCatalog'))


@app.route('/item/<int:item_id>/delete/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])



def deleteItem(item_id):

    item = Item.query.filter_by(id=item_id).one()
    category = item.category
    user = g.user
    # check if user is owner
    if user == item.owner:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            flash("Item " + item.name + " deleted")
            db_session.delete(item)
            db_session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('showCategory', category_name=category.name))
        else:
            return render_template('deleteitem.html', item=item, user=g.user)
    else:
        flash("Unauthorized user")
        return redirect(url_for('showCatalog'))


@app.route('/login')



def loginUser():

    # send user back to the source page
    uri = github_callback_url + "?next=" + request.referrer
    return github.authorize(redirect_uri=uri)
    # if session.get('user_id', None) is None:
    #   return github.authorize()
    # else:
    #   flash('User is already logged in')
    #   return redirect(url_for('showCatalog'))




@app.route('/logout')
def logoutUser():

    session.pop('user_id', None)
    flash('User logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('showCatalog'))


@app.route('/github-callback')



@github.authorized_handler
def authorized(oauth_token):

    next_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('showCatalog')
    if oauth_token is None:
        # something went wront
        flash("Authorization failed")
        flash(request.args.get('error'))
        flash(request.args.get('error_description'))
        flash(request.args.get('error_uri'))
        return redirect(next_url)
    user = User.query.filter_by(github_access_token=oauth_token).first()
    if user is None:
        # new user is not in database
        user = User(name="", github_access_token=oauth_token)
        db_session.add(user)
    # save oauth token in database
    user.github_access_token = oauth_token
    db_session.commit()
    session['user_id'] = user.id
    flash("User " + user.name + " logged in")
    return redirect(next_url)


@github.access_token_getter



def token_getter():

    user = g.user
    if user is not None:
        return user.github_access_token

# Registers a function to run before each request.


@app.before_request



def before_request():

    g.user = None
    if 'user_id' in session:
        g.user = User.query.get(session['user_id'])
        g.user.name = github.get('user')["name"]
        g.user.avatar = github.get('user')["avatar_url"]
        db_session.add(g.user)
        db_session.commit()


@app.after_request



def after_request(response):

    db_session.remove()
    return response


@app.route('/json')



def catalogjson():

    list = []
    items = Item.query.all()
    for item in items:
        list.append({"name": item.name,
                     "id": item.id,
                     "description": item.description,
                     "category": item.category.name,
                     "image": item.image,
                     "owner": item.owner.name
                     })
    return jsonify({"items": list})

# run flask server if script is started directly
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = False
    app.secret_key = app_secret
#    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

server conf file :

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  ec2-52-37-69-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
        ServerAdmin catalog@57.37.69.144
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/catalog/catalog.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/catalog/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/catalog/static
        <Directory /var/www/catalog/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel error
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

the session was set to the flask null session (which is the default implementation) which again throws an error.

Solution is to set it to :

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'